# segmentation fault (core dumped) error sorting string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I'm supposed to write a code that puts names into alphabetical order using  pre-set names, and this is what i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{

const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
string temp;                        
string names [NUM_NAMES] = {"Collins, Phil", "Simpson, Bart", "Allen, Jim",
                            "Griffen, Jim", "Stamey, Marty" "Rose, Geri",
                            "Taylor, Swift","Johnson, Jill", "Alison, Jeff",
                            "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean", 
                            "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg",
                            "Ravens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy",
                            "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth" }; 


for (int k=0; k < NUM_NAMES; k++ )
{     for (int i=0; i<NUM_NAMES; i++)
      {
           if ( names[i] > names [i+1])
              {
                temp = names[i];
                names [i] = names[i + 1];
                names [i + 1] = temp;
              }

      }

}
cout << names [0] << endl;

int k = 1;
int  i = 0;
while (k <= NUM_NAMES)
{
      cout << names [i] << endl;
k++;
i++;
}


return 0;
}
```

it compiles with no error but when i try to run it "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" appears... any help in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: _`if ( names[i] > names [i+1])`_ `names [i+1]` goes out of bounds if `i == NUM_NAMES -1`

Comment: would you mind if I asked you to explain it though? i set 'i' to 0, i thought that it would use position 1 in the array

Comment: @AngelEspinoza: But it is a `for` loop that runs from `0` to `19`. On the last iteration `19 + 1 = 20` which is out of bounds.

Comment: The array is valid between 0 and `NUM_NAMES` -1. `names [i+1]` can read from `names[NUM_NAMES]` which is one entry too far.

Comment: @AngelEspinoza  _would you mind if I asked you to explain it though?_ Of course not: _"i set 'i' to 0, i thought that it would use position 1 in the array"_ That's all fine, the problem is you go to access one value beyond your array when you execute `names [i+1]` in the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting memory, that does not belong to you - in this line:

```
names [i+1] = ...
```

In C++ (and many other languages) arrays are indexed from `0`. So an array of size `N` is valid for indexes from `0` to `N-1`. Your `for` loop iterates through `0` ... `NUM_NAMES - 1`, but inside, you use index `i+1` which is `NUM_NAMES` for last iteration.

To solve this problem, you could iterate through `1` ... `NUM_NAMES - 1`:

```
for (int k=1; k < NUM_NAMES; k++ )
```

And work on `names[i-1]` and `names[i]`:

```
if ( names[i-1] > names [i])
{
    temp = names[i - 1];
    names [i - 1] = names[i];
    names [i] = temp;
}
```

*(Or leave it as it is now, but change execution condition of the loop to `k < NUM_NAMES - 1`)*

Also, instead of this:

```
temp = names[i];
names [i] = names[i + 1];
names [i + 1] = temp;
```

You could simply do:

```
std::swap(names[i], names[i + 1]);
```

Comment: ooooh, okay, i think i understand now. so I was asking the program to go out side of the array towards the end then?

Comment: You were basically writing to (and reading from) memory location after the last element of the array.

Comment: ah..okay, well thank you so much for clearing that up for me, I greatly appreciate it